# Which filter to manually deserialize incoming JSON to a specified type

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an application with ASP.NET Core WebAPI.  What I would like to do is create a filter that I can apply to my controller method that will then let the system know to explicitly convert the incoming JSON object into a specified type.

For example, this is what I envision being able to do:

```
[HttpPost()]
[MyFilter(typeof(MyType))]
public IActionResult Post(MyType model)
{
  ....
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because the incoming JSON object does not match (at all) the structure of "MyType".  So I have written a special converter whose logic I can call from this Filter.  I want to explicitly state the type and not try to infer it from values within the JSON object (which is, in my case, impossible).

Comment: Look at the docs please, it's pretty well documented on how to create (and register) a [Custom Model Binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding). If you still have concrete issues with your implementation of it, ask a new question ^^

Comment: Just keep in mind to register your custom model binder provider as **first** in the model binder providers collection, i.e. `options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new AuthorEntityBinderProvider());` from the example, which inserts it in the first position of the collection. When it returns `null` the other providers will be called

Comment: The way you do this is via the parameter type, i.e. because your action accepts `MyType`, the modelbinder will automatically deserialize the JSON into an instance of `MyType`. However, you *do* need to decorate your param with `[FromBody]` to have it accept JSON. Perhaps that's the issue you're having?

Comment: I have a very unusual scenario where the incoming JSON object has a set structure but needs to be 'deserialized' into an arbitrary type.  This is why I want to use an attribute which I can in turn provide parameters specific to *that* controller method which will inform the converter to convert that JSON object into the specified type.  I cannot use CustomModelBinder as that is injected into the pipeline.  Again, the type must be explicitly specified for a particular controller method because each controller + method may use an entirely different type, but the JSON object is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to do is create a filter that I can apply to my
>   controller method that will then let the system know to explicitly
>   convert the incoming JSON object into a specified type.

Filter is not quite right tool for performing custom model binding you described. You should not reinvent the wheels here: custom model binding should be performed by means of (sorry for this pun) custom model binder.

If the only argument against model binder is:

> I cannot use CustomModelBinder as that is injected into the pipeline.

then ASP.NET Core provides an elegant way how to apply model binder to specific action arguments, without adding it to the whole pipeline. This could be done via `ModelBinder` attribute applied to action paramter, which specifies the binder in `BinderType` property.

Here is a sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyTypeBinder))] MyType model)
{
    return Ok();
}

public class MyTypeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Put your custom MyType binding code here
    }
}
```